# nodejs and heroku and passport does not initialise the cookies in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, passport.js

I am using nodejs and react with passport. I am using the following config in backend:

```
app.use(cors({ 
    origin: getProductionURL(), 
    credentials: true}));

//Dong know whats this but without it is not working AT ALL!!
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'secretcode',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
        maxAge: 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 48 hours
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));
```

The frontend, once is loaded, is getting the user :

```
export const userContext = createContext({});
const Context = props => {

    const [userState, setUserState] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(getProductionURL('/api/get-user'), { withCredentials: true })
            .then(res => {
                if (res?.data) {
                  console.log(res.data);
                    setUserState(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);


  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={userState}>{ props.children }</userContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

The problem is on development is working. But on production, when I go to application tab from inspection, the Cookie tab is empty.

After the callback is initiated, I get the get-user from backend:

```
 userRouter.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['public_profile']}));
 userRouter.get('/facebook/callback',
   passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
    failureRedirect: getProductionURL('/login'), 
    failureMessage: true, 
    successRedirect: getProductionURL('/profile') }),
   (req, res) => res.redirect(getProductionURL('/profile')));
 

userRouter.get('/get-user', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {   
        res.status(200).json(req.user);
    } 
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```